# Зал слушал, и(,) когда он закончил играть, многие стали ему аплодировать

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Нужна ли запятая после **и**? И какой характер употребления: строгий или факультативный?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Правило таково. Запятая на стыке союзов ставится, если после первого союза следует одиночный союз в придаточной части:**Собака приостановилась, и, пока она стояла, человек видел, как солнечный луч обласкал всю полянку (Пришв.).**

Если после первого союза следует двойной союз, то запятая на стыке союзов не ставится. Это случается, когда подчинительный союз имеет в главной части предложения слово **то:** ***Прокофьев, одеваясь на
ощупь в кромешной темноте, говорил, что писательство — самое тяжелое и заманчивое занятие в мире и что если бы он не был геологом, то наверняка бы сделался писателем (Пауст.) —*** **в данном предложении имеются две изъяснительные части, соединенные союзом и... что и что; но в качестве второй придаточной выступает сложноподчиненное предложение (если... то);**

См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации.Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина. — М: аст, 2009.

Comment: К величайшему моему сожалению, нужна :) Она практически всегда после "и" противоречит интонации, приносимой в жертву идее учебного разбора на двусторонне обособляемые обороты. Может, в РАН когда-нибудь образумятся и велят отбрасывать знаки ложного препинания по окончании расстановки запятых и точек над ждущим реабилитации "ё".

Comment: @ Alex_ander, а почему к величайшему сожалению?

Comment: Потому что мешает чтению: запнуться можно в том месте, где невозможна пауза (после "и" она бывает только в тостах). Знак препинания не оправдывает здесь своего назначения.

Comment: Alex_ander, в том-то и дело, что интонационный принцип письма занимает последнее место. Там, где есть пауза, порой нет запятой и наоборот.

Comment: Вот это и плохо: лишние знаки приводят к интонационным ошибкам при первом прочтении.